# Django two forms interconnected in single template

Tags: django

I have another model which is like below

```
class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I just want to create a form which will render all users from django `User` model with upper model connected. When click single Status button it will just save that field. I'm using CreateView. How to do that?

```html
<form method="post" action="">
User1 <input type="checkbox" name="status" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Status"/>
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
User2 <input type="checkbox" name="status" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Status"/>
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
User3 <input type="checkbox" name="status" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Status"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [Django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/) ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/) from Django. Through this way, you can set 2 forms in one, get fields from both forms and save them with a single button.

For example, you have two models bounded by a ForeignKey in your **models.py** file :

```
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...

class MyModelB(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(MyModelA, ...)
```

Then, in your **forms.py** file, you have to bound these both forms thanks to `formsets` :

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from .models import MyModelA, MyModelB

MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(MyModelA, MyModelB, form=MyModelBForm, extra=1, max_num=1)
```

With this line, your models will be set into the same django form in your template.

Now, in your **views.py** file, you have to call your formset :

```
class MyClassCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModelA
    template_name = 'path/to/your/template'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyClassCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_form'] = MyFormSet(self.request.POST or None)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        document = context['my_form']
        if document.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            document.instance = self.object
            document.save()
        return super(MyClassCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And finally, in your **template.html** file, you can call your formset :

```
<form method="post" action="" novalidate>
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}
     {{ my_form }}   
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" />
</form>
```

Hopfully it could help you to set your Django formsets

Comment: Thanks bro. I already tried this. Is there any way to set user from foreign key automatically with loop? and extra field will be dynamically number of total user row?